# How to validate inputTextarea with read only?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to validate read only inputTextarea component in primefaces (PF) wizard running inside of PF dialog. After reading many threads from here I decided to use inputHidden component to handle that. However it does validation right but after entering a value in the inputText then click on commandButton I noticed that foo bean's applyName method never got invoked. I would like to believe that it has to do with JSF lifecycle.

My goal is foo.applyName method kicks in so that foo.name is returned with a proper value and evaluated so that I can click on Next button in the wizard.

Without having a validation mechanism, foo.applyName indeed puts a value (String type) into a name property and I can move on to next step.

```
<p:panelGrid id="table">
  <p:inputTextarea readonly="true" value="#{foo.name}" />
  <h:inputHidden id="name" required="#{empty foo.name}" requiredMessage="missing name" />
  <p:message for="name" />
</p:panelGrid>

<h:inputText value="#{foo.someVar}" />
<p:commandButton value="Apply Missing Name" update="table" action="#{foo.applyName}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that when you click the commandButton, you are submitting the inputTextArea as well as the inputText. JSF sees that the empty field you submitted is required and does not allow the request to continue.

There are a couple ways to fix this

1. Give the inputText an id and use the 'process' attribute on the commandButton to specify the fields you want to submit e.g. process="@this someVar"
2. Put the inputTextArea and inputText fields in separate forms so that the applyName commandButton will not process both.